# Looping over items in the database and updating variable extracted from API

Tags: php, wordpress, rest, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I'm building a script as a study project to retrieve the prices from an API and update the database every 5 min. The code below is working. 
**But it's a nightmare to maintain right now**, as I have to list each product by its ID as well as referencing the api keys manually.

I tough about doing a foreach loop linking the products in the database and api based on their SKU and updating the price from there, but I just can't seem to pull it off.

```
<?php

require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
use Automattic\WooCommerce\Client;
use Automattic\WooCommerce\HttpClient\HttpClientException;

$woocommerce = new Client(
    'http://example.com',
    'ck_xxxxxxxxxxx',
    'cs_xxxxxxxxxxx',
    [
        'wp_api' => true,
        'version' => 'wc/v2',
       // 'query_string_auth' => true
    ]
);

function parse_json( $file ) {
    $json = json_decode( file_get_contents( $file ), true );

    if ( is_array( $json ) && !empty( $json ) ) :
        return $json;  
    else :
        die( 'An error occurred while parsing ' . $file . ' file.' );

    endif;
}

$url = 'https://username:password@apiservice.com/apis/v1.0/c1212kj1n1n1b112';

$json = parse_json($url);

//Updates simple products prices. Product #586:
$data = [
    'update' => [
        [
            'id' => 586,
            'regular_price' => $json['name' == 'Product 1']['regular_price']
        ]
    ]    
];

print_r($woocommerce->post('products/batch', $data));

// Update product variations. Product #588:
$data = [
    'update' => [
        [
        'id' => 589,
        'regular_price' => $json['product_variation[0]']['regular_price']
        ],
                [
        'id' => 590,
        'regular_price' => $json['product_variation[1]']['regular_price']
        ],
        [
        'id' => 591,
        'regular_price' => $json['product_variation[2]']['regular_price']
        ],
    ]
];

print_r($woocommerce->post('products/588/variations/batch', $data));

?>
```

API output example:

```
[
    {
        "product_id": "100",
        "type": "simple",
        "parent_product_id": "",
        "name": "Product 1",
        "description": "A short description",
        "regular_price": "26.78",
        "manage_stock": "1",
        "stock": "5",
        "weight": "0",
        "attribute_name": "",
        "attribute_value": "",
        "has_variations": "",
        "image": "site.com/image1.png",
        "sku": "10010"
    },
    {
        "product_id": "200",
        "type": "variable",
        "parent_product_id": "",
        "name": "Product 2",
        "description": "A short description",
        "regular_price": "0",
        "manage_stock": "0",
        "stock": "0",
        "weight": "0",
        "attribute_name": "Color",
        "attribute_value": "",
        "has_variations": "1",
        "image": "site.com/image2.png",
        "sku": "11010"
    },
    {
        "product_id": "",
        "type": "product_variation",
        "parent_product_id": "200",
        "name": "",
        "description": "A short description",
        "regular_price": "3.70",
        "manage_stock": "1",
        "stock": "100",
        "weight": "0",
        "attribute_name": "Color",
        "attribute_value": "Red",
        "has_variations": "",
        "image": "",
        "sku": "11011"
    },
```

Is that possible to achieve?

Comment: Are you updating product prices from Wordpress/Woocommerce to an external service via the WP API or the contrary? … Do you need to get all your WooCommerce products every 5 mn? Where is the part of the code that is sending products $data outside (or may be the data is get from outside)? …

Comment: I'm sorry I wasn't clear about that. I'm trying to get the prices from the API into woocommerce product database. The code is in a PHP file that is run every minute via a cron job (I couldn't think of any other way of getting live prices like that).

Comment: You need all products (prices) from woocommerce at once? if yes how do you combine them in one $data (meaning the necessary array structure … I suppose that product variations needs their parent variable product ID…)